# Angular $HTTP blank data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Explanation of my issue is below:
Here's my HTML.

```
   <!doctype html>
   <html ng-app="myApp">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Angular.js test</title>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
   </head>

      <body>
      <div ng-controller = "MyController" id="myDiv">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="item in flow">
                {{item.name}}       
          </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Here's my custom angular

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
        $scope.flow = [];
        $http.get('js/data.json').then(
            function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $scope.flow = data ;
           }, 
            function(data){
                console.error('error');     
        });
     }]);
```

My data.json document contains are below.

```
 [
    {
      "name":"Barot Bellingham",   
      "reknown":"Royal Academy of Painting and Sculpture",

    },
    {
      "name":"Jonathan G. Ferrar II",
      "reknown":"Artist to Watch in 2012",

    }
 ]
```

If I put this data directly in the controller it works PERFECT!
However if I put this data in a separate file (js/data.json) and use $http the data comes back BLANK although the success function was TRUE and ok. Even The list bullets repeat but the data is blank.

Is there any particular reason why this wont work?? Please please Help!![image: ![This an example of the app working with the data is place inside the controller]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPa7P.png)

[image: Here is an example of it not working when I put the data in a separate file]

Comment: try `$scope.flow = data.data ;` .. `$http` returns a promise object with the data as property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. Your http response comes back an object which includes the following properties. ([from Angular docs on `$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http))

- data – `{string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
- status – `{number}` – HTTP status code of the response.
- headers – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
- config – `{Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
- statusText – `{string}` – HTTP status text of the response.

---

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.flow = [];
    $http.get('js/data.json').then(
        function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $scope.flow = data.data;
       }, 
        function(data){
            console.error('error');     
    });
 }]);
```